# Convert Python dictionary to yaml

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have a dictionary, I am converting dictionary to yaml using `yaml` module in python. But Yaml is not converting properly.

```py
output_data = {
    'resources': [{
        'type': 'compute.v1.instance',
        'name': 'vm-created-by-deployment-manager',
        'properties': {
            'disks': [{
                'deviceName': '$disks_deviceName$',
                'boot': '$disks_boot$',
                'initializeParams': {
                    'sourceImage': '$disks_initializeParams_sourceImage$'
                },
                'autoDelete': '$disks_autoDelete$',
                'type': '$disks_type$'
            }],
            'machineType': '$machineType$',
            'zone': '$zone$',
            'networkInterfaces': [{
                'network': '$networkInterfaces_network$'
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

I tried :

```py
import yaml
f = open('meta.yaml', 'w+')
yaml.dump(output_data, f, allow_unicode=True)
```

I am getting `meta.yaml` file as following:

```
resources:
- name: vm-created-by-deployment-manager
  properties:
    disks:
    - autoDelete: $disks_autoDelete$
      boot: $disks_boot$
      deviceName: $disks_deviceName$
      initializeParams: {sourceImage: $disks_initializeParams_sourceImage$}
      type: $disks_type$
    machineType: $machineType$
    networkInterfaces:
    - {network: $networkInterfaces_network$}
    zone: $zone$
  type: compute.v1.instance
```

Here, `{sourceImage: $disks_initializeParams_sourceImage$}` and `{network: $networkInterfaces_network$}` are written like a dictionary. It means inner
dictionary contents are not converting to yaml.

I also tried,

```py
output_data = eval(json.dumps(output_data)) 
ff = open('meta.yaml', 'w+')
yaml.dump(output_data, ff, allow_unicode=True)
```

But getting same yaml file content.

How can I convert a nested dictionary into yaml in Python?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, `PyYAML` chooses the style of a collection depending on whether it has nested collections. If a collection has nested collections, it will be assigned the block style. Otherwise it will have the flow style.

If you want collections to be always serialized in the block style, set the parameter `default_flow_style` of dump() to `False`. For instance,

```
>> print(yaml.dump(yaml.load(document), default_flow_style=False))
a: 1
b:
   c: 3
   d: 4
```

Documentation: https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: For Python 3.8+ and PyYAML 6.x, the following works `print(yaml.dump(document))`

Answer (score 2):

At the time this question was asked, it was `default_flow_style=None` by default but [since PyYaml 5.1](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/commit/507a464ce62c933bf667b2296a96ad45f0147873), it's been `default_flow_style=False` by default, so for recent versions of PyYaml, OP's initial code would produce the desired output.

```py
with open('meta.yaml', 'w+') as ff:
    yaml.dump(output_data, ff)
```

In case you're wondering how one should know which arguments are valid, `dump` is a wrapper for `dump_all`, you can use `yaml.dump_all` for that, e.g. `help(yaml.dump_all)` shows all valid arguments.

The above code can be written as:

```py
with open('meta.yaml', 'w+') as ff:
    yaml.dump_all([output_data], ff)
```

`dump_all` can also return a string if no stream is passed.

```py
s = yaml.dump_all([output_data])
print(s)

resources:
- name: vm-created-by-deployment-manager
  properties:
    disks:
    - autoDelete: $disks_autoDelete$
      boot: $disks_boot$
      deviceName: $disks_deviceName$
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: $disks_initializeParams_sourceImage$
      type: $disks_type$
    machineType: $machineType$
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: $networkInterfaces_network$
    zone: $zone$
  type: compute.v1.instance
```